# Trying to get Distinct() and/or GroupBy(...) in returned ToList

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

The code is working and returning a good list with (6) items.
However, we are seeing duplicates productSKU. We want to do a 
DISTINCt productSKU.

```
pM = (from oo in ctx.option1 
      where mArray.Contains(oo.option1Code)
      select oo)
      .Select(o => new ProductMatch
    {
        productSKU = o.option1Code,
        productPrice = o.price,
        option1Desc = o.option1Desc
    }).ToList();
```

I have tried to add Distinct() after the Lambda but I still get (6) items.

I am also getting error when I add GroupBy(...) "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: Can you post your Distinct() and GroupBy() calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
pM = (from o in ctx.option1 
      where mArray.Contains(o.option1Code)
      let t = new 
      {
         productSKU = o.option1Code,
         productPrice = o.price,
         option1Desc = o.option1Desc
      }
      group o by t into grp
      select new ProductMatch
      {
         productSKU = grp.Key.option1Code,
         productPrice = grp.Key.price,
         option1Desc = grp.Key.option1Desc
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: The above code worked! I had to make one minor change.


`pM = (from oo in ctx.option1 
      where mArray.Contains(oo.option1Code)
      select oo)
      .GroupBy(o => o.option1Code)
      .Select(g => **g.FirstOrDefault()**)
      .Select(o => new ProductMatch
      {
        productSKU = o.option1Code,
        productPrice = o.price,
        option1Desc = o.option1Desc
      }).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation of IAbstractDownvoteFactor's answer

```
pM = (from oo in ctx.option1 
      where mArray.Contains(oo.option1Code)
      select oo)
      .GroupBy(o => o.option1Code)
      .Select(g => g.First())
      .Select(o => new ProductMatch
    {
        productSKU = o.option1Code,
        productPrice = o.price,
        option1Desc = o.option1Desc
    }).ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you use linq heavily and are open to using libraries, there is [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) that gives you `DistinctBy()` extension and several other useful extensions.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a Distinct on a lamba expression, the Distinct only looks at the EntityKey for the distinct comparision.  You will need to implement your own IEqualityComparer for your select.

```
internal class UniqueProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductMatch>
{
    public bool Equals(ProductMatch x, ProductMatch y)
    {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(x,y)) return true;

        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y,null))
           return false;

        return x.productSKU == y.ProductSKU && x.productPrice == y.productPrice && x.option1Desc == y.option1Desc;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(ProductMatch match)
     {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(match,null)) return 0;

        return match.productSKU.GetHashChode() + match.productPrice.GetHashCode() + match.option1Desc.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Then in your lamba, change it to this:

```
pM = (from oo in ctx.option1 
      where mArray.Contains(oo.option1Code)
      select oo)
     .Select(o => new ProductMatch
    {
        productSKU = o.option1Code,
        productPrice = o.price,
        option1Desc = o.option1Desc
    }).Distinct(new UniqueProductComparer()).ToList();
```